# Perl - Calculate difference between two timestamps

Tags: perl, date

I am trying to calculate the difference between two timestamps in the following format:

```
15:45:30.125
```

I have tried using the Date::Parse package in Perl with the following:

```
my $s1 = str2time( $timestamp1 );
my $s2 = str2time( $timestamp2 );
```

and simply subtracting $s1 and $s2 to find the difference but it is just rounding to the nearest second rather than including the milliseconds... is there an alternative or a way of including the millisecond count when subtracting the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you use the [`Time::HiRes::Value`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::HiRes::Value) module which supports arithmetic on objects that contain separate second and microsecond values — the same as the value returned by `Time::HiRes::gettimeofday`. It also provides a convenient stringification overload

You would need to write a simple parsing subroutine though, like this

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 

use Time::HiRes::Value;

my $t0 = parse_time('15:45:30.125');
my $t1 = parse_time('18:12:46.886');

print $t1 - $t0;

sub parse_time {
  my ($h, $m, $s, $ms) = shift =~ /\d+/g;
  Time::HiRes::Value->new(($h * 60 + $m) * 60 + $s, $ms * 1000);
}
```

**output**

```
8836.761000
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks good. I'm having one minor problem though.... Cannot install the Time::HiRes::Value module through cpan as it is failing at the test phase with an 'illegal division by zero' error... I am using dwimperl on windows.

Comment: @Shaw: I had that. For some reason CPAN won't install it if left to itself. If instead you do `look Time::HiRes::Value` then it will download and unpack the module and put you in the temporary directory where it was unpacked to. You can then follow the remaining  instructions in [`perlmodinstall`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodinstall.html) which is `perl Makefile.PL`, `dmake`, `dmake test`, and `dmake install`. It's worth trying the same thing with other recalcitrant modules.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the date and time zone of the times, then you can use the following:

```
$ perl -MDateTime::Format::Strptime -E'
   my $format = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
      pattern   => "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%3N",
      time_zone => "local",
      on_error  => "croak",
   );

   my $dt1 = $format->parse_datetime("2015-10-01 00:00:00.000");
   my $dt2 = $format->parse_datetime("2015-10-01 03:00:00.100");

   say $dt2->subtract_datetime_absolute($dt1)->seconds
      + ( $dt2 - $dt1 )->nanoseconds / 1e9;
'
10800.1
```

If you don't have the date and time zone of the times, then what you are asking is impossible. Observe how changing just the date can change the result.

```
$ perl -MDateTime::Format::Strptime -E'
   my $format = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
      pattern   => "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%3N",
      time_zone => "local",
      on_error  => "croak",
   );

   my $dt1 = $format->parse_datetime("2015-11-01 00:00:00.000");
   my $dt2 = $format->parse_datetime("2015-11-01 03:00:00.100");

   say $dt2->subtract_datetime_absolute($dt1)->seconds
      + ( $dt2 - $dt1 )->nanoseconds / 1e9;
'
14400.1
```

If you do happen to know the time zone, and if that time zone happens to be UTC, and if you're ok with being off by a second, then an answer is possible without knowing the date.

```
my $s1 = str2time( $timestamp1 ) + ( $timestamp1 =~ /(\.\d+)/ ? $1 : 0 );
```

Comment: Very often, time information — especially experimental data — is *relative* rather than *absolute*, and so doesn't belong to any time zone and ignores leap seconds. They are devices that allow for different people in different places to agree about what time and day it is, and that is often irrelevant, although it can be nice if an event log matches the clock on the wall. You won't find people in the CERN laboratories, for instance, interested in such insignificancies. The OP says that he is dealing with timestamps like `15:45:30.125`, which carries no date anyway.

Comment: @Borodin, 1) All times are relative. 2) If they are actually durations (measured in 60 minute hours and 60 second minutes) relative to the same timestamp, then he probably shouldn't be using a date-time library as he is currently doing. But if he does, he can treat them as two UTC times, and he can use the provided solution.

Comment: When we speak in absolute terms we *always* mean relative to a basis that is so commonplace that it doesn't need to be specified. Only mass is an inherently absolute measurement. And your solution involves inventing an unnecessary and meaningless date to add on to the timestamp so that it will parse.

Comment: @Borodin, Adding `+ ( $timestamp1 =~ /(\.\d+)/ ? $1 : 0 )` to the code does not involve "inventing an unnecessary and meaningless date to add on to the timestamp so that it will parse." Did you even read my answer????